# iOS: check system version in #define and do different stuff, compiler error

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, c-preprocessor

I am using `MKReverseGeocoder` for iOS < 5 and `CLGeocoder` for iOS >= 5, but got a warning because `MKReverseGeocoder` is deprecated, then I tried to do something like:

```
#define SYSTEM_LOWER_THAN_5 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"5.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

#if SYSTEM_LOWER_THAN_5
@interface TelstraLocationService () <MKReverseGeocoderDelegate>
#else
@interface TelstraLocationService ()
#endif
```

but I got an error:

> Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression

This is caused by the macro that can only be evaluated at runtime. Is there a way to get rid of the warning (without changing deployment target)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to simply get rid of the compiler warning (since you have accounted for any potential problems and made the explicit decision to ignore it), surround the triggering code with these compiler directives:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    // some code that uses something deprecated
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

You want to be as specific as you can to avoid inadvertently ignoring other valid deprecation warnings.  Surround just the `MKReverseGeocoderDelegate` if you have another protocol before and after it, otherwise just surround the entire @interface block:

```
// option 1
@interface TelstraLocationService () <
    SomeProtocol

    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
          MKReverseGeocoderDelegate
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop

    AnotherProtocol>

// option 2
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

@interface TelstraLocationService () <MKReverseGeocoderDelegate>

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Surround any calls to `reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:` or `reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:` with the same compiler directives to silence deprecation warnings for them as well.